# LVM Difference in paths for mounts

Tags: linux, mount, lvm

So I can do the following:

`mount /dev/datavg/datalv /mnt`

or

`mount /dev/mapper/datavg-datalv /mnt`

Are these the same? Is there an advantage to one over the other? Is one considered better practice to use?

Comment: Check if they return the same device when listing with `ls -la`. If that's the case, they are equivalent. However, I've always preferred `/dev/mapper` because it is easier to read and mentally sort in `/etc/fstab` (at least for me).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I especially appreciate you showing me how to find the info for myself. 

Both symlinks appear to point to the same device.

Comment: You're welcome, I've expanded my comment as an answer and added a reason as to why you should use `/dev/mapper` devices in `/etc/fstab`. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check whether they are the same see what `ls -la` lists for both files:

```
$ ls -l /dev/datavg/datalv 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 2013-03-01 19:02 /dev/datavg/datalv -> /dev/mapper/datavg-datalv
$ ls -l /dev/mapper/datavg-datalv 
brw------- 1 root root 253, 0 2013-03-01 19:02 /dev/mapper/datavg-datalv
```

As you see, there's a small difference:

`/dev/mapper/datavg-datalv` is a **device file** while `/dev/datavg/datalv` is a **symbolic link**.

Although both paths they are **interchangeable in commands** like `mount` or `fdisk`:

```
# mount /dev/datavg/datalv /mnt
# mount /dev/mapper/datavg-datalv /mnt
```

my experience is that you should **use the device file in `/etc/fstab`**, for example:

```
/dev/mapper/datavg-datalv /mnt ext3 acl,user_xattr 1 2
```

How come I recommend this? A couple of years ago I had an issue with a server that didn't come up after a reboot and the cause was a missing device symlink for an LVM filesystem listed in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: I think the best method to mount partitions is using `UUID` instead of a fixed block device path in `/etc/fstab`. Because udev sets up these device files and if your udev is broken you have exactly the issue as you describe. Using `UUID` you didn't have these problems at all.

Comment: Yes, you can use UUIDs, but remember that `mount` looks for  entries in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` (see `man mount`), which are symlinks to the device files. The symlinks are created by udev (find the specific rule grepping for "by-uuid" in `/lib/udev/rules.d/` or `/etc/udev/rules.d/`), so when using UUIDs you depend on udev too.

Comment: This is probably the best and most comprehensive answer I've gotten. Thank you very much

Comment: On systems I've checked (Ubuntu 20.04, Centos 7) they're both symlinks to the same place.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this changed since the question was asked, but the [man pages for LVM2](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/lvm.8.html) state (emphasis mine):

> A directory bearing the name of each Volume Group is created under `/dev` when any of its Logical Volumes are activated. Each active Logical Volume is accessible from this directory as a symbolic link leading to a device node.  **Links or nodes in `/dev/mapper` are intended only for internal use** and the precise format and escaping might change between releases and distributions.  **Other software and scripts should use the `/dev/VolumeGroupName/LogicalVolumeName`** format to reduce the chance of needing amendment when the software is updated. Should you need to process the node names in `/dev/mapper`, you may use `dmsetup splitname` to separate out the original VG, LV and internal layer names.

Therefore, you should use `mount /dev/datavg/datalv /mnt`

Regarding [`dmsetup splitname`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/dmsetup.8.html):

> ```
>    splitname device_name [subsystem]
>           Splits given device name into subsystem constituents.   The  default  subsystem  is
>           LVM.  LVM currently generates device names by concatenating the names of the Volume
>           Group, Logical Volume and any internal Layer  with  a  hyphen  as  separator.   Any
>           hyphens  within  the  names are doubled to escape them.  The precise encoding might
>           change without notice in any future release, so  we  recommend  you  always  decode
>           using the current version of this command.
> ```

Here's a usage example:

```
# dmsetup splitname /dev/mapper/datavg-datalv
VG                 LV         LVLayer
/dev/mapper/datavg datalv
```

Interestingly, on my system, `/dev/mapper/datavg` does not exist so I'm puzzled by that output.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are spot-on about checking to see if they are identical.  However, I have found a place where the syntax can make a difference for some flavors of Linux:

In Ubuntu 14.04, I've discovered that LVM isn't brought online automatically for mount points with a device path of /dev/VG/LV -- the device path must be in the form /dev/mapper/vg--lv before the system will bring up LVM (i.e. invoke vgscan/vgchange) at boot time.